# Uploading files to the server jQuery ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ASP.NET to create an website backend and also I am using bootstrap and jquery to handle pages layout and user interaction. I need to upload some file(s)(i.e., file of photo type) to the server. I am already used the HTML5 file API to read the files from the local system but I do not know how to send it for saving on the server do I have to implement some sort of ASP.NET Web API to do the storing and if so what is the URL that I will pass to the post method within the jquery? I mean will I have to write something like this http://server-ip:port/directory-to-my-api or I can just refer to my api within the jquery like ./myapi/mycontroller

Comment: this question is too broad you should be posting code with what you've attempted

Comment: Yes the question is too broad, however, I am asking about a specific thing if I need to send files to be stored on the server and I am having a web api to do this how the url of the jQuery post method will look like? Should I write the server ip address/port number combination or I can simply write the something like (./myapi/mycontroller). Regarding the code no problem I will post my code regarding this issue.